# Making a backup of my game and it says it can't find the UnityLockfile?

Tags: unity

I am trying to make a backup copy of my game that I have been working on for the past 3 years and I have it saved on an external hard drive and I want to put a copy onto my desktop.

The files and game is copying just fine until it reaches the same issue:

"Item not Found.
Could not find this item
This is no longer located in F:/Gamefolder/Gamename/Temp. Verify the item's location and try again."

I follow the path and don't see any folder called Temp and I don't recall one being there either but what also bothers me is when I tried it earlier, it said it couldn't copy it because it was open in Unity, long after I close it(and I checked task manager to be sure)

Does anyone know what this file is or what it does? Also I've put the metadata on so that the game opens normally without me having to set up everything again. Does anyone know if this is necessary to do that?

I'm not a beginner but I'm not a pro, I learn as I go so if any screenshots could be provided they would be a massive help :)

Comment: I guess you should not need to worry if it is inside of Temp folder.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better answered on the Unity Community site

Comment: @MrCranky just because a question is on-topic elsewhere does not necessarily make it off-topic here.

Comment: True, but it is a question not about games development but about how Unity works. The criteria for migrating to SO is "Would a professional game developer give me a better/different/more specific answer to this question than other programmers?" Feels like the same criteria should apply here: would a gamedev give a different answer to someone on the Unity community site, if not then perhaps this question belongs there.

Comment: @MrCranky *"Would a professional game developer give me a better/different/more specific answer to this question than other programmers?"*    **Yes**, since Unity is a **game**-development software.

Comment: I agree with Charanor which is why I asked here because I thought it was more appropriate.

Comment: @MrCranky, Unity is a Game Developer engine. How it works is most definitely related to what it does. Also, why would we consider something off topic because it would be better answered on a *non-stack exchange site*? By your logic, every Unity question would be off-topic, because the official Unity Answers page has a greater change of being answered by the actual developers. **Vote to leave open**.

Comment: Unity is software primarily but not exclusively used for making games. That doesn't mean every question relating to Unity is best answered by a game-dev. Some questions are about "how do you set up Unity" and have nothing to do with games at all. Just because my PC can be used to make games doesn't mean that every PC question is best answered by a game-dev. If other people feel like it belongs here then that's fine, close vote retracted, just trying to improve the signal to noise ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files in the `Temp` and `Library` folders can be ignored when copying, backing up, or checking in a Unity project. Aside from being very large and inconvenient to move around, everything in these folders is derived data which will be regenerated by Unity when you reopen the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the popup saying the lock file not found. you can copy and paste it to the new folder while Unity editor is closed and it will not do that.